# How to install OCI8 extension on PHP 7.4 on macOS Catalina or Big Sur?

Tags: php, oracle, macos-catalina, oci8

I already have PHP 7.4.11 and Apache 2.4.46 installed on my Mac via Homebrew.

Then installed Oracle instant client & sqlplus (v19.3.0.0.0):

```
$ brew tap InstantClientTap/instantclient
$ brew install instantclient-basic
$ brew install instantclient-sqlplus
```

Next is to install the OCI8 extension, by running:

```
pecl install oci8
```

PECL prompted me this:

> Please provide the path to the ORACLE_HOME directory. Use
> 'instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib' if you're compiling with
> Oracle Instant Client [autodetect] :

I was not sure what is this `/path/to/instant/client/lib`, so I ran `locate sqplus`:

> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/.brew
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/.brew/instantclient-sqlplus.rb
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/bin
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/bin/sqlplus
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/lib
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/lib/libsqlplus.dylib
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/lib/libsqlplusic.dylib
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/libexec
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/libexec/sqlplus
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/instantclienttap/homebrew-instantclient/Formula/instantclient-sqlplus.rb
> /usr/local/bin/sqlplus /usr/local/lib/libsqlplus.dylib
> /usr/local/lib/libsqlplusic.dylib /usr/local/opt/instantclient-sqlplus
> /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/instantclient-sqlplus

OK, let's try these 2 directories:

**/usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/lib**

> checking Oracle ORACLE_HOME install directory...
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/lib checking
> ORACLE_HOME library validity... configure: error: Oracle library
> directory not found in
> /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/lib ERROR:
> `/private/tmp/pear/temp/oci8/configure
> --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config --with-oci8=/usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/19.3.0.0.0dbru/lib' failed

**/usr/local/lib/**

> checking Oracle Instant Client directory... /usr/local/lib/ checking
> Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... configure: error: Oracle
> Instant Client SDK header files not found ERROR:
> `/private/tmp/pear/temp/oci8/configure
> --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/local/lib/' failed

**/path/to/instant/client/lib** produced the same error like the former.

What's the correct one, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd install the new [Instant Client 19.8 DMGs from Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html).  The download page and the packages contain instructions.  Also see the steps at [Notarized macOS Oracle Instant Client Packages Make Installation Easier](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/notarized-macos-oracle-instant-client-packages-make-installation-easier).  Install the Basic and SDK packages - and maybe SQL*Plus if you want that too.  The path you would give at the PECL prompt will be /Users/yourname/Downloads/instanclient_19_8 but you can move that directory if you want to put it somewhere else.

It could be that the brew packages are putting the header files in a place that the OCI8 install script isn't aware.  By using the DMGs, the headers will be found.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. After updating to Big Sur (and upgrading PHP to v8), your suggestion work. The packages I downloaded were: basic, sqlplus, sdk, jdbc, and odbc. I think the reason my compilation failed is because I forgot to download the sdk file, which is necessary for building PHP extension.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  For future readers: to use PHP OCI8 or PDO_OCI you don't need the jdbc, odbc or sqlplus packages (though the latter is useful for general ad hoc SQL queries).