# Can't run SQL*Plus on macOS 11 (Big Sur)

Tags: python, oracle, macos, sqlplus

i install oracle instant client basic with this commands but it's not work

```
//mount instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.dmg

cd /Volumes/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru

./install_ic.sh

ln -s ~/Downloads/instantclient_19_8/libclntsh.dylib /usr/local/lib/

echo 'export PATH=~/Downloads/instantclient_19_8:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile
```

i have this error in python too:

```
DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help
```

Comment: The `ln -s` may not buy you anything??  Did you use `init_oracle_client()` ? See the cx_Oracle doc [Using cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client() to set the Oracle Client directory
](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#using-cx-oracle-init-oracle-client-to-set-the-oracle-client-directory).

Comment: it's don't work on Big Sur

Comment: If you can give more detail, we might be able to help.  SQL*Plus is know to run on Big Sur

Comment: For example, see the comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64654317/4799035.  If PHP can run on Big Sure, then Python and SQL*Plus can too.

Comment: Finally SQL*Plus worked on but cx-oracle can't connect.

Comment: You need to give more detail.  Show the code you are running.  Did you read the cx_Oracle manual or https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/avoiding-the-dpi-1047-error-with-nodejs-node-oracledb-5-on-macos-and-windows ?  It's the same on cx_Oracle just with a different function name.

Answer (score 1):

What is MacOS without Homebrew? What is Oracle Database without sqlplus?

I haven't tried Big Sur yet but this Tap works beautifully on Catalina. Perhaps someone can verify?

Make sure to download the client-zip-files first.

```
# install on MacOS
brew tap InstantClientTap/instantclient
cp ~/Download/instantclient*.zip /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/instantclienttap/homebrew-instantclient
brew install instantclient-basic
brew install instantclient-sqlplus
brew install instantclient-tools
```

Comment: Another reference is https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/notarized-macos-oracle-instant-client-packages-make-installation-easier which

Comment: What error does SQL*Plus give?  I assume you have an Intel chip?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that looking at the [installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html#ic_osx_inst), Big Sur is not supported.

[image]

#### Update

Since I had posted the previous screenshot, it seems that Big Sur is now supported for the 19.8 client.

[image]

Comment: That page has a header that says the last updated date is `2018-04-19T19:17:32Z`. Big Sur was not released until `2020-11-12` so it is not surprising that it is not mentioned on a page create 2½ years earlier.

Comment: As of now, Instant Client 19.8 has been certified on Big Sur.